# Who has created this group? Who have created this group?

Tags: pronouns, relative-pronouns

I'm much confused about these two sentences. 
Which one is the correct one?  I heard that we can't use " Who are, who were,  who have"?  Is this okay to say?  One of my friends said.

His explanation is given below.

'Who have' is not correct. 'Who' isn't followed by are, have or were in a question wether the subject is singular or plural. In your example no matter the group is created by a person or more than one person, we would only ask who has created to find out about the subject.

Actually, we discussed this above mentioned question. After that, he shared his views which have been added by me over here. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: In my opinion, who has created this group? This question is suitable:)

Comment: *Who is not followed by are...." *Who are they* to tell this! :P

Comment: What is "who" in the sentence?  Is it a subject or something else?

Answer (score 1):

In my American English I would entirely remove any version of the word "have." The resulting sentence would be "Who created this group?"

As for all situations, I would say that conjugations of "to be" can be used, but not conjugations of "to have."

Examples:
"Who are they?"
"Who are you?"
"Who were the first people to sail to America?"
"Who were the first men on the moon?"